# Attaching the downloaded excel file to Gmail using Selenium Webdriver with Python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

How to attach the downloaded Excel file to Gmail and send an email using Selenium Webdriver with Python?

Brief explanation of the scenario:

This downloaded excel file is the one which has been the result of navigating some screen in xyz web application which i have been successfully automated using selenium webdriver  using Pycharm.

I need to automate this downloaded excel file/sheet which i can attach to my email in gmail and send a email to xyz party.

Comment: Hey Shan, please include more details about what you tried to solve this issue in your question.

Comment: Off-topic.  Might want to try the API: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in Windows try AutoIT for manipulating OS windows - ie. Windows Explorer windows for uploading files:

https://www.autoitscript.com/site/

It's easy to write a script in AutoIT.

Once you have the script, convert it to .exe and in Python execute the .exe file with `os.system("[path-to-your-exe-file]")`